# how to achieve rotating background on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, parallax, skrollr

folks I want to make a demo design of [this](http://www.ginventory.co/) and I got confused how to achieve this. should I go for parallax scrolling or should I prefer skrollr or scrollmagic or just simple css with few jquery code? suggest the simplest way to achieve this.
Thanks :)

Comment: Make with css and active step class with simple javascript or jquery based on scroll

Comment: yeah ok sure!!!

Comment: how the js will detect when to change active step class?

Comment: Define a breakpoint based on scroll for each step

Comment: ok then will doo thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example;

Html

```
 <div class="rotate"></div>
```

Css

```
body{
    height: 1000px;
    background: yellow;
}

.rotate{
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/zZ3fMuh.png");
    width: 101px;
    height: 102px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Js

```
$(function() {
    var rotation = 0, 
        scrollLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var newLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
        var diff = scrollLoc - newLoc;
        rotation += diff, scrollLoc = newLoc;
        var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
        $(".rotate").css({
            "-webkit-transform": rotationStr,
            "-moz-transform": rotationStr,
            "transform": rotationStr
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: check my fiddle bro

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case they used **CSS** with the help of **JavaScript** but the part what you are watching at is CSS (really fluent) and it get executed my an scroll handler.

In this specific case they used the [transform: translate3d()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d) property to rotate the yellow background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the background when scrolling, look this: https://codepen.io/sarkiroka/pen/gByRmd

In nutshell it uses the sidebar elements for this effect. This elements has `:before` property with background setting, and a little javascript calculate the rotating degree from the `scrollTop`. And this javascript overwrite the defined css rule transform property.